# Captiva Designer ODBC - Flow does not error out even if it returns more than one rows

Tags: captiva, captiva-designer

I am working with Captiva Designer and implemented a flow. In the ODBC setup, I have checked the checkbox which says "Error if more than one row found".

[image]

I tested the flow and intentionally used a query which would return multiple rows. However the flow picks up the first query and process next steps accordingly.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For marking it as error, it will not mean to give any batch level error. However it will mention "More than one row found for fetch", in description attribute, in export module at document level.

you can handle the case accordingly in your flow using the above value.